# How to translate tinymce integrate in VUEJS component

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, components, tinymce

I try to translate tinymce vue component in fr. My code :

```
<editor id="test" :init="{ selector: '#test', language_url: '/static/fr_FR.js' }" :initial-value="div.data.inputTextarea" api-key="[my-api-key]" @input="updateTiny" v-model="tinyHTML"></editor>
```

I see the tinymce text editor, but not translated and no erros in the console.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you see in the browser's console from the attempt to load that URL for the language file?

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to provide `language: 'fr_FR'`.
The language and filename needs to be same e.g. `language_url: '/static/hy.js',  language: 'hy'`

Full version for you :)
`<editor id="test" :init="{ selector: '#test', language_url: '/static/fr_FR.js', language: 'fr_FR' }" :initial-value="div.data.inputTextarea" api-key="[my-api-key]" @input="updateTiny" v-model="tinyHTML"></editor>`